# Targeting a div with specific class and id

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I have following div and script for lightbox content:  https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight

(Note, the lightbox plugin simply "mirrors" the whole div even with the id, so it will look like there are two div with one identical id)

```
<div class="regular" id="my_id">
    Lightbox content
</div>
::before
<div class="regular special_div" id="my_id"> //identical id as the first div
    Lightbox content
</div>


<script>
...
success: function(data){
        jQuery('#my_id').html(data);
...
</script>
```

So, with this lightbox plugin, selected `div` is shown in a lightbox and adds a class called (in this case) `"special_div"`.

I have ajax function to load a page inside of this div with `#my_id`.
The problem is that the ajax is loaded in the first `div` container with the id=#my_id.

With the lightbox opened, the div now has a class of "special_div".

Is there a way to target the second `div` in the jquery function with the ".special_div" ?

Comment: `Targeting a div with specific class and id` just target the id because ID should always be unique

Comment: I know. but this plugin simply copies the whole div and "mirrors" with the same ID and same class. So I am trying to somehow bypass it.

Comment: you can't have identical id's

Comment: try this $("#id:last")

Comment: If you must then chain the classes `jQuery('.regular.special_div')`

Comment: @MuhammadAtif better $('.regular:last')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just be more specific with your selector. Remember that jquery selectors work like css selectors.

```
$(".regular.special_div#my_id")
```

Comment: This approach was the simplest and worked like a charm! =) Thanks man! Learned something new.

Answer (score 2):

To target the div with the class **special_div** use:

```
jQuery('.special_div#my_id').html(data);
```

You can also use the **:eq()** selector jQuery provides, to target an element by index:

```
jQuery('#my_id:eq( 1 )').html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

**html**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="regular" id="my_id">
    Lightbox content
</div>
::before
<div class="regular special_div" id="my_id"> //identical id as the first div
    Lightbox content
</div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
jQuery(".container>div:nth-child(2)").html(data);
```

[nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".regular + .regular").html(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you can chain a class like so:

```
jQuery('#my_id.special_div');
```

This should reference the reflected div. However I wouldn't go leaving 2 identical IDs like that in the DOM. This is bad HTML markup, IDs should be individual and may cause warnings / errors. [Read this for more information](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127178/two-html-elements-with-same-id-attribute-how-bad-is-it-really)

Instead you could use (for this scenario):

```
jQuery('.regular:last');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Mhmm, I agree regarding the bad markup. It looks like the plugin simply mirrors the whole div container. Took some time to figure out how to work around it :P thanks for the help tho! :)